# how to send file to another host with ftp_pasv() via PHP?

Tags: php, ftp

can I send a file to another host through **PHP** and **ftp_pasv** function?

I used the following code:

```
$ftp_server = "ftp.domain.com";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$ftp_username = "USERNAME";
$ftp_userpass = "PASSWORD";
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true);
$copyBU = ftp_put($ftp_conn, $file, $file, FTP_ASCII);
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

but it copies the file corruptly and the destination zip file does not open. Is there a problem somewhere? Thank you for helping me fix it.

Comment: Have you try with `FTP_BINARY`  in `ftp_put` function ?

Comment: A ZIP file is unquestionably a binary file, yet you're using ASCII mode for the transfer. That seems like a recipe for disaster. Use FTP_BINARY instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a file to another host using FTP in PHP with ftp_pasv(), you can follow these steps.

```
<?php
$ftp_server = 'ftp.domain.com'; 
$ftp_user = 'USERNAME';
$ftp_pass = 'PASSWORD';
$remote_file = '/path/to/remote/file.txt'; // Replace with the remote file path and name
$local_file = '/path/to/local/file.txt'; // Replace with the local file path and name

// Create an FTP connection
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

if ($ftp_conn) {
    // Log in to the FTP server
    if (ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)) {
        // Turn on passive mode (PASV)
        ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true);

        // Upload the local file to the remote server
        if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
            echo "File uploaded successfully.";
        } else {
            echo "Error uploading file.";
        }

        // Close the FTP connection
        ftp_close($ftp_conn);
    } else {
        echo "FTP login failed.";
    }
} else {
    echo "Unable to connect to FTP server.";
}
?>
```

> Please try with FTP_BINARY instead of FTP_ASCII.

Comment: There's no functional difference between your code and the code posted by the OP, other than the change in mode to FTP_BINARY. Have you tested this?

Comment: Hello @TangentiallyPerpendicular I've mentioned there should need to use FTP_BINARY instead of FTP_ASCII, I've paste code because if use will set conditional code then user can easily debug it.